# How to migrate Bot Services to framework 4.3 ussing AppSettings

Tags: botframework

Microsoft Bot Framework 4.3 has changed the way Bot is configured deprecating .bot file and migrating application configuration data to AppSettings.json file, but it also changed the way to feed Bot Configuration. I've reviewed all documentation and download templates, however, it doesn't describe how to migrate from old design to a new one when having multiple services like LUIS and QnA with multiple databases like I have.

Here is my current project piece of code to load all services:

Startup.cs

```
services.AddSingleton(sp => botConfig ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"The .bot config file could not be loaded. ({botConfig})"));
        services.AddSingleton(sp => new BotServices(botConfig, Configuration));

        // Configure endpoint based on current environment
        var service = botConfig.Services.Where(s => s.Type == "endpoint" && s.Name == _environment).FirstOrDefault();
        if (!(service is EndpointService endpointService))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"The .bot file does not contain an endpoint with name '{_environment}'.");
        }
```

BotServices.cs

```
public BotServices(BotConfiguration botConfiguration, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            foreach (var service in botConfiguration.Services)
            {
                switch (service.Type)
                {
                    case ServiceTypes.Luis:
                        {
                            var luis = (LuisService)service;
                            if (luis == null)
                            {
                                throw new InvalidOperationException("The LUIS service is not configured correctly in your '.bot' file.");
                            }

                            var app = new LuisApplication(luis.AppId, configuration[luis.AppId], luis.GetEndpoint());
                            var recognizer = new LuisRecognizer(app);
                            this.LuisServices.Add(luis.Name, recognizer);
                            break;
                        }

                    case ServiceTypes.QnA:
                        {
                            var qna = (QnAMakerService)service;
                            if (qna == null)
                            {
                                throw new InvalidOperationException("The QnA service is not configured correctly in your '.bot' file.");
                            }

                            var qnaEndpoint = new QnAMakerEndpoint()
                            {
                                KnowledgeBaseId = qna.KbId,
                                EndpointKey = configuration[qna.KbId],
                                Host = qna.Hostname,
                            };

                            var qnaMaker = new QnAMaker(qnaEndpoint);
                            QnAServices.Add(qna.Name, qnaMaker);
                            break;
                        }
                }
            }
        }
```

Having this on place I was able to consume any service by just passing BotServices to my bot, however I don't find the correct way to do this with Microsoft Bot Framework 4.3

I'd appreciate any help on this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do it pretty much the same way, but instead of your first code block, you:

1. [Create an IBotServices Interface for BotServices](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/14.nlp-with-dispatch/IBotServices.cs)

```cs
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.Luis;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.QnA;

namespace Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples
{
    public interface IBotServices
    {
        LuisRecognizer Dispatch { get; }
        QnAMaker SampleQnA { get; }
    }
}
```

2. ...so that you can [use Dependency Injection in Startup.cs](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/14.nlp-with-dispatch/Startup.cs#L26)

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IBotServices, BotServices>();
```

I recommend reviewing the [NLP with Dispatch Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/14.nlp-with-dispatch)

Comment: Thanks Michael, this is exactly what I was looking for! Regards